# How to define the cut off point?

Tags: group-differences

I have population of 218 people operated on after a certain event. They are operated on from day 30 to day 911 after the event . Some of them were OK (0) and some got a complication (1). I would like to determine when is the best time to perform an operation, because I believe that the sooner the operation is, the lesser is the possibility for complications. So I need a point to say: It is different (better) to perform the operation before day xxx, then after this day.
Any suggestions?
Bojan, SLO

Comment: Can you show us some plots of your data?